# .exe file of c# project using mysql server

Tags: c#, mysql, windows

I am building a C# application which connects to a MySQL database. It is working fine on my development computer. I want to build the application into an 'exe' or executable file which can be run on different computers. Where do I start and how can I build the application so that it runs on another computer. It should still be able to access and modify the database.

Comment: Well, for this to work for pc's that are not in the same netwerk where the MySQL server is accessible you will need to install MySQL server or make it accessible. What is your actual problem that you are facing?

Comment: User of my application needs to open the database everytime??? It is not feasible. I want to make a. exe file of my application which will install mysql in users pc. But the problem is they need to connect to server everytime. again, they have to connect to database using admin password.

Comment: If you don't want your application to connect to a central MySQL database via your network or the Internet, then you should consider using a different database. [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) or [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) are both relational databases that are self contained and I think would suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

If you see in bin exe must me building
There in *.exe.config you can modify connection string

It will be easier if you create installer